# Qt4: how to send QString inside a struct via QSharedMemory

Tags: struct, qt4, qstring, qsharedmemory

I have a struct

```
struct control_data{
    int column_number;
    QString cell;
};
```

I need to send it to another thread with the help of QShareMemory. I [read](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/26254-QSharedMemory-and-C-objects) that you can't do this because QString contains pointers inside. Any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

You have to serialize your struct to a Byte array. You can always convert your `QString` to a `const char*` like this:

```
myString.toStdString().c_str();
```

But serializing a QString should work.

- The first step is to serialize your struct to a `QDatastream` using Qt, [example here](http://www.ics.com/blog/object-serialization-and-persistence-using-qdatastream).
- Then once your struct can be read and written you can pass it to a shared memory.

A complete example of using QSharedMemory can be found [here](http://qt.shoutwiki.com/wiki/QSharedMemory_example).

Here is the relevant code:

```
// First, test whether a shared memory segment is already attached to the process.
// If so, detach it
if (sharedMem.isAttached())
{
    sharedMem.detach();
}

...

QBuffer buffer;
buffer.open( QBuffer::ReadWrite );
QDataStream out( &buffer );
out << youStruct;
int size = buffer.size();  // size of int + size of QString in bytes

if ( !sharedMem.create( size ) ) {
    return;
}

// Write into the shared memory
sharedMem.lock();
char *to = (char*)sharedMem.data();
const char *from = buffer.data().data();
memcpy( to, from, qMin( sharedMem.size(), size ) );
sharedMem.unlock();
```

Comment: It is a byte array. Look closely, we copy the array with memcpy to another byte array belonging to the shared memory. You cannot serialize a pointer which points to a non-shared memory zone.

Comment: So should i use const char* in a struct or i can leave qstring with qbuffer and qdatastream?

Comment: Read my updated answer, it has everything to answer you problem.